# Standard c++ containers in windows driver

Tags: windows, driver, device-driver

I know that I can't use the STL library directly when developing windows driver. But I really need to use the standard c++ containers ( vector, map,etc ) . Any one knows some kernel based implementation of the STL for use under kernel mode, or some other similar library that at least implements the standard containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out this one http://bazislib.sysprogs.org/. This lib contains patched version of STLPort .